# Permutations with repetition and combinations with repetition

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

I'm having some difficulty explaining why should we use permutations with repetition instead of combinations with repetition when we are choosing from a set of objects, with subsets of indistinguishable objects.

Let's assume that we have a bag with 10 balls, 4 green and 6 red.
We will remove some balls with replacement, i. e., after each ball is removed, the color is noted and the ball goes again into the bag and we repeat the process $n$ times.
We want to compute the probability of getting 3 green balls and 2 red balls in any order.

---

The way I would solve it is by using the Binomial distribution:

$$ \displaystyle P = \binom{5}{3} \cdot \left( \frac{4}{10} \right)^3 \cdot \left( \frac{6}{10} \right)^2 = \binom{5}{3} \cdot \frac{4^3 \cdot 6^2}{10^{5}} $$

So, we would consider the probability of getting 3 green balls and 2 red balls and the number of ways we could observe a sequence of these 3+2 balls.

The final expression makes evident that we could equivalently solve this problem by using permutations with repetition: we would consider that we got 3 green balls, 2 red balls and the number of ways of getting a sequence of 3+2 balls with those colors, divided by the number of ways of getting any 5 balls with replacement.

I strongly believe that the above is the correct way to solve the problem.

---

However, if I think about combinations with repetition, I could try to solve the same problem in the following way:

$$ \displaystyle P = \frac{ \displaystyle \binom{4+3-1}{3} \cdot \binom{6+2-1}{2} }{ \displaystyle \binom{10+5-1}{5} } = \frac{5!}{3! \cdot 2!} \cdot \frac{ 6 \times 5 \times 4 \times 7 \times 6 }{ 14 \times 13 \times 12 \times 11 \times 10 }$$

Which is different from the solution using the Binomial distribution.

The first expression uses combinations with repetition: selecting 3 from 4 (green balls), with replacement; and selecting 2 from 6 (red balls) with replacement; divided by selecting 5 balls from 10 (4 green + 6 red balls) with replacement.

The final expression would lead me to think that this formulation is alike considering 6 green balls and 7 red balls from which we would remove, respectively, 3 and 2 balls without repetition and this would be multiplied by the number of possible sequences of those 3+2 balls. The expression would be divided by the ways of getting 5 balls from a bag with 14 (and not 6+7) balls. So, it seems that we would get 2 virtual green balls and 1 virtual red ball in the numerator and 4 virtual balls in the denominator.

---

If the balls were removed without replacement, the probability would be:

$$ \displaystyle P = \frac{ \displaystyle \binom{4}{3} \cdot \binom{6}{2} }{ \displaystyle \binom{10}{5} } = \frac{5!}{3! \cdot 2!} \cdot \frac{ 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 6 \times 5 }{ 10 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7 \times 6 } = \frac{5!}{3! \cdot 2!} \cdot \frac{ \displaystyle \frac{4!}{(4-3)!} \cdot \frac{6!}{(6-2)!}}{ \displaystyle \frac{10!}{(10-5)!} }$$

The first expression corresponds to the number of ways to select without replacement of 3 green balls out of 4, and the number of ways to select without replacement 2 red balls out of 6, divided by the number of ways of selecting any 5 balls from 4+6 balls.

So, in this case, using combinations (the first expression, which is more straight forward) and permutations (the final expression) is equivalent as long as we consider the number of ways to sort the 5 selected balls in the final expression.

---

**My question is: why is wrong to use combinations with repetition to solve the problem with replacement?**

My tentative answer would be: because the combinations with repetition should only be used when the $n$ objects are distinguishable.

I would also appreciate if the answers could provide some references.

Happy New Year!

Comment: This is a long question to read, and I have not finished reading it all... but to answer your first few points, you need to remember that probability is not always going to be "number of good cases / total number of cases."  The combinations with repetition failed to deliver the correct result precisely because the different outcomes counted like that are not equally likely to occur.  There are two outcomes when playing the lottery: you win or you lose.  You do not win the lottery with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ however.

Comment: When considering probability questions like this, it is critical to understand in what way the experiment is performed.  *How* did we manage to pull balls and decide if we got the event we wanted or not?  If we were in some backwards scenario where we wrote down each of the outcomes counted by stars-and-bars on a piece of paper and picked a piece of paper at random, then sure... we could have the answer as given by combinations with repetition.  That is not the typical interpretation however.  Typically, we imagine picking a ball from those available, then picking another, then another etc...

Comment: "*My tentative answer would be: because the combinations with repetition should only be used when...*"  They should almost *never* be used in *any* probability scenario, and certainly almost never used as a method of calculating the size of a sample space.  The times when they should be used should be made very explicitly clear that they deviate from the typical manner in which random processes usually occur.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @JMoravitz. I was wondering if the events from the combinations with repetition were or not equiprobable. Following your comments we could say that the set $\{G_j, G_j, G_j, R_m, R_m\}$ (three times the same green ball and two times the same red ball) should appear only once, while the set $\{G_j, G_k, G_l, R_m, R_n\}$ (3 "different" green balls and two "different" red balls) should appear $3! \times 2!$ times, meaning that they are not equiprobable.

Comment: A strategy is often to make few changes to the question, and check if the process is still correct.  We have a bag with 4 green and 6 red. We can change to 40 green and 60 red, or even 2 green and 3 red, it should not change the result. Check with your formula if it changes the result. If theresult changes, it means that the formula is not correct, and probably, you can understand the root cause of the error.

Comment: The other point about undistinguishable objects is that you can always consider that objects are distinguishable. You just write  a number on each ball, and now they are distinguishables. And obviously, probability do not change !  ALWAYS consider that objects are distinguishables, to avoid errors.